# Updating Replicated Database

Tags: sql-server, replication

What is the optimal way to update a schema on a publishing database that is push-replicated is SQL Server (2012).

Currently we disable replication, update the schema, re-enable replication and run a new snapshot.

As the database grows this strategy will become problematic as the snapshot will get bigger which will make deployments take longer over time.

Is there a way to do this without a new snapshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema changes can be made using ALTER syntax at the publisher.  By default the schema change will be propagated to subscribers automatically, publication property **@replicate_ddl** must be set to true.  There are considerations to make depending on the type of schema change and the publication type.  This is covered in [Make Schema Changes on Publication Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx) and [Replicate Schema Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152562.aspx).